# How to delay CPU intensive tasks to allow render to happen

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a React application in which multiple sequential CPU intensive tasks happen. I would like to track the progress of the overall operation.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      status: 'not started'
    }
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.status === 'starting') {
      this.cpuIntensive()
      this.setState({status: 'first task done'})
    }
    if(this.state.status === 'first task done') {
      this.cpuIntensive()
      this.setState({status: 'second task done'})
    }
    if(this.state.status === 'second task done') {
      this.cpuIntensive()
      this.setState({status: 'finished'})
    }
  }
  
  cpuIntensive() {
    let result = 0
    for (var i = Math.pow(7, 8); i >= 0; i--) {  
      result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i);
    }
  }
  
  handler() {
    this.setState({status: 'starting'})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.status}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handler}>START</button>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

In this snippet when you click `START` the state will indeed change, we go through `componentDidUpdate` but the component do not re-render.

To make it work like I want, I can do:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {status: 'not started'}
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.status === 'starting') {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.cpuIntensive()
       this.setState({status: 'first task done'})
      }, 100)
    }
    if(this.state.status === 'first task done') {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.cpuIntensive()
        this.setState({status: 'second task done'})
      }, 100)
    }
    if(this.state.status === 'second task done') {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.cpuIntensive()
        this.setState({status: 'finished'})
      }, 100)
    }
  }
  
  cpuIntensive() {
    let result = 0
    for (var i = Math.pow(7, 8); i >= 0; i--) {  
      result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i);
    }
  }
  
  handler() {
   this.setState({status: 'starting'})
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.status}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handler}>START</button>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

It looks bad IMO. I'm looking for alternatives :)

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT: web workers are not an option**

Comment: I think your solution is just fine. If you want to make it more elegant, how about creating a mothod that wraps the `setTimeout` in a promise with a callback and resolves it immediately? (you don't actually need the 100 ms delay)

Comment: Thank you @GhassenLouhaichi. What do you mean when you say I don't need 100ms? Do you think that 100ms is too long or that I don't need a delay at all?

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { this.cpuIntensive(); this.setState({status: 'first task done'}) });` worked just fine for me (basically a timeout of 0).

Comment: True, thanks. I'll go along with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start your operation in your `handler`, and use `setTimeout()` to chain / allow for renders to happen in between. Then you would not need to use the react state for starting those consecutive operations.

Another option would be to use a WebWorker.

Comment: Thank you. The action is triggered by the user, like in the snippet. And a web worker, I think it's what you mean, is not an option.

Comment: That was my first try. The problem is that you update the state multiple times in the same method. And `setState` is async so you have to deal both with `setTimeout` and `setState`'s callback. That's why I rely on `componentDidUpdate`... but maybe it's a bad idea.

Comment: @mthpvg It depends on your goals. If you want to force the in between updates to visualize progress before you start the next operation then its fine. If the operations are small enough, you can leave it to React, to decide if it wants to batch those state changes or not.

Comment: You're right my goal is to force the in between updates to visualize progress. But no the operations are not small enough. So, you're probably right in saying that my solution is enough but I was hoping after a more elegant solution :)